# Trying to creating a playlist (audio) in HTML, Javascript and onclick of file, it has to send the absolute path to java?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

read multiple audio files from local and display in website (HTML). The audio files have to be href and onclick, it has to send the absolute path to java, and java plays that song. I have done the back end, this UI, I cant figure it out. please help

Answer (score 1):

If file is in your local, you can do it by providing common base path. And Iterate over all the list. Also you need to provide a playlist for it, on which you going to iterate.

```js
function changeAudio() {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  var src = audio.children["0"].src;
  if(src !== "nextSrc") {
    src = "commonbase value" + "next file";
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeAudio()">Change audio</button>
```

See updated snippet

```js
var basePath = "assets/source/";

var file = {
  "first" : "firstFile.mp3",
  "second" : "secondFile.mp3",
  "third" : "thirdFile.mp3"
};

function changeAudio() {
  var player = document.getElementById('audio');
  var source = player.children[0].src;
  if(source === "") {
    player.children[0].src = basePath + file.first;
  } else {
    player.children[0].src = getSource(source);
    console.log(player.children[0].src);
  }
}

function getSource(source) {
  for(var key in file) {
    if(file[key] === source.substring(source.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, source.lastIndexOf("3") + 1)) {
      var index = getCurrentIndex(key);
      return file[Object.keys(file)[index + 1]];
    }
  }
}

function getCurrentIndex(keyToFind) {
  var i=0;
  for(var key in file) {
    if(key === keyToFind) {
      return i;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeAudio()">Change audio</button>

<audio controls id="audio">
  <source src="firstFile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, you see, you have hard coded the .mp3 file, but I would like to provide a file and want to retieve the file content to an array and display them. Once diplayed, onclick on an element, it has to send the absolute path to Java.

Comment: that will not be an issue. still you can do that.